# bijective maping from natural number set to prime numbers

Tags: real-analysis

I think the prime number set is countable . But I am not able to define a bijective mapping from natural number set to prime numbers.

Comment: Sure it's countable. The primes are a subset of the natural numbers, so they can't be uncountable. But the primes do not form a finite set either. There's only one option left.

Answer (score 6):

Just define recursively:

$$p_1=2$$
$$p_{n+1}=\text{next prime }>p_n$$
or, more precisely, using the well order property of $\Bbb N$:
$$p_{n+1}=\min\{a\in\Bbb N: a>p_n \wedge a \text{ prime}\}$$
There is nothing special here. You can do exactly the same for every infinite subset of $\Bbb N$.